# Kitchen Cabinet Replacement

Tags: cabinets

I have one compartment of kitchen cabinet (dimension 18x35x24) in my rental house that got water damage that I would like to replace. See picture. I can easily find the exact dimension from Home Depot or Lowe's for only about $150.00, click link [*here*](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Easthaven-Shaker-18x34-5x24-in-Frameless-Base-Cabinet-with-Drawer-in-Unfinished-Beech-EH1835B-GB/300794342). But unfortunately the style is quite different. I would like to buy one that is closely similar in style.

Do you know of any retailer that I can order online? Or do you have any other solution? My rental house is in the suburbs of Dallas, Texas. Thank you for your time and pointer.

[image]

Comment: A kitchen and bath type of store will probably have a better selection.  Most big box stores only carry what sells fast and so have a more limited selection of styles.

Comment: Questions about goods and services are off topic possibly rewording and a photo that is not washed out by the reflection could bring help and get those down votes reversed. I did not down vote but vote to close.

Answer (score 1):

Not all cabinets have this, but you should look inside your cabinets (and on the underside of drawers) to see if you can find a manufacturer label. This will help you significantly narrow down where to look, because you can get a catalog from that specific manufacturer or find a local distributor for that manufacturer who can show you samples in the store.

However, you should expect to have a ***very*** hard time matching the color because the ones that are in your house have weathered with time. Be prepared to re-stain/varnish/paint the entire kitchen, or choose a contrasting color instead of trying to match the color exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you! Will look for the manufacturer's label.

Answer (score 0):

There are some online stores that sell drawer fronts. You provide them the measurement and pick an edge profile, you should be able to find the same edge profile. You can also order a drawer. If the actual cabinet frame is messed up then this won't work but if you want to post that as a separate question you can probably find out how to fix the frame.

Comment: Thank you for your help.